# How to hide suggested groups in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, ads

At the side there's a lot of suggested groups that I find annoying and offensive, for example ones involving religion. Is there anyway I can hide them? Can I use Ad block plus to hide them?

Answer (score 1):

There is a browser extension called Social Fixer that can, among many other things, permanently hide parts of Facebook pages.

You can get it at http://socialfixer.com for Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

After it's installed, hover over the Suggested Groups section, and an X should appear. Clicking the X will hide the area permanently (or until you change your settings to get it back again).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, though I'm not sure it's worth it to install an add on that would slow down the browser just for one site. But I'll give it a try!

Comment: I hear you on that. For what it's worth, I find the add-on extremely helpful in general, so if you spend enough time on FB, you may grow to love it. But if not, no hard feelings ;)

Comment: Current versions of social fixed require you to do something before you get the "X". Enabling "Hide/Show parts of screen" on the pull down menu is necessary first.